# Try/ Except, not returning the except

Tags: python

I am trying to use try and except for some code. I have been able to get the try portion of the code to work appropriatly, but not the except portion. I am using the ValueError, but have tried the NameError and IndexError. 
What am I missing?

```
string1 = input("Enter a string:")
d = dict(enumerate(string1))
try:
    enter_value = input("Enter a value(should be in the initial string1):")
    if enter_value in d.values():
        print("Value found.")
except ValueError:
    print("Value not found.")
```

The code I have written produces the correct response when the enter_value is in the dict(). But displays:
"Enter a value(should be in the initial string1):d"

When it is not in the dict()

Comment: What's the point of `d = dict(enumerate(string1))`?

Comment: This code doesn't work because at no point is there an error. A try except will only reach the `except` if there is an error. I'm thinking you thought the line `if enter_value in d.values():` would throw an error if `enter_value` isn't in `d.values()` but it wont, it will simply evaluate `enter_value in d.values()` to `False` and therefor skip over the if statement.

Answer (score 5):

Use the code:

```
string1 = input("Enter a string:")
d = dict(enumerate(string1))

enter_value = input("Enter a value(should be in the initial string1):")
if enter_value in d.values():
     print("Value found.")
else:
    print("value not found.")
```

What that error does is it produces an error if the value is incorrect but you want to see if the value is in the string or not so just check it and then put out a response.

Answer (score 1):

Your code is performing correctly. You are asking if `enter_value` is in the list `d.values()`, but if it is not it wouldn't throw an error, but instead just break out of your `if` statement because you are not indexing or anything too tricky. You can catch this logic with an `else:` block like this:

```
string1 = input("Enter a string:")
d = dict(enumerate(string1))
try:
    enter_value = input("Enter a value(should be in the initial string1):")
    if enter_value in d.values():
        print("Value found.")
    else:
        print("Value not found.")
except:
    print("There was an error!!")
```

Although with this specific code I don't suspect there will be any errors to catch (that I can think of at least, I'm sure if you tried hard enough you could break it though XD)

Comment: Thank you for the feedback. Much appreciated.

Comment: @KButler No problem! FYI it's common practice that when a solution that you find adequate for your problem is posted to click the check mark by their post so future users can know what worked. Also, when you get 15 rep you can up-vote helpful questions and answers! Welcome to StackOverflow

Answer (score 1):

As mentionned  `if enter_value in d.values():` will return true or false but it won't raise an exception so don t use a try here because it's unecessary.

Also instead of using a dict you can simply check if the value is present in the string

```py
string1 = input("Enter a string:")
enter_value = input("Enter a value(should be in the initial string1):")
if enter_value in string1:
    print("Value found.")
else:
    print("Value not found.")
```

If you want to understand try/except, check this quick exemple

```
try:
    1 / 0
except ZeroDivisionError:
    print('error, unable to divide by 0')
```

Comment: You don't need to use either, you can check a string directly

Comment: thanks @juanpa.arrivillaga you totally right. I fixed it

Answer (score 1):

You can do what you're trying to do, like this:

```
string1 = input("Enter a string:")
d = dict(enumerate(string1))
try:
    enter_value = input("Enter a value(should be in the initial string1):")
    if enter_value not in d.values():
        raise KeyError('Value not found.')
    print(f"Value found.")
except KeyError as e:
    print(e)
```

I noticed the other answers are pointing out other ways of doing it, but if you want to use exceptions, this is how.

Typically, you don't raise an exception when looking for a *value* in a dict though, it's typically more when a key is missed. Like this:

```
d = {'a': 1, 'b': 2, 'c': 3}
try:
    _ = d['d']
except KeyError:
    print('Key not found.')
```